# how to split value into rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
data = {'user_id': {2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Q1': {2: '1', 3: '8', 4: '2'},
 'Q2': {2: '4', 3: '3', 4: '2, 3, 4'},
 'Total Traffic(MB)': {2: 261.1186, 3: 179.18564, 4: 351.99208}}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

how to split last row into 3 rows with same data but only one 'Q2' value per row  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
(df.assign(Q2=df['Q2'].str.split(', '))
   .explode('Q2')
)
```

output:

```
   user_id Q1 Q2  Total Traffic(MB)
2        3  1  4          261.11860
3        4  8  3          179.18564
4        5  2  2          351.99208
4        5  2  3          351.99208
4        5  2  4          351.99208
```

Comment: thank you so much )

Comment: @alexsmolyakov note that the resulting Q2 column is of type string, you might want to convert to int using `astype(int)`